# Pandas / excel / persmission denied

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file test_info.xlsx in the same director as my python programme. I paste information into the excel and import it into an sqlite db via the python programme.

Great all works. Until today I have been able to keep the excel document open, save it and run the python code with no issues.

However now I am getting the below:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test_info.xlsx'
```

Python will now only read the file if I close the excel file which makes the process very cumbersome. The only thing I have changed recently is updating onedrive.

Is there a way back to where it was / what have I done?

Comment: Can you please share your code where you are importing the excel file.

Comment: df = pd.read_excel('test_info.xlsx)